# Xen Dom0 and DomU in different subnets on Ubuntu/Debian

Tags: networking, ubuntu, debian, xen, subnet

ISP gave me two IP configs:

```
10.0.1.5 / 255.255.255.0 / gw 10.0.1.1
10.0.9.8 / 255.255.255.0 / gw 10.0.9.1
```

I've set up **Dom0** is **10.0.1.5** with bridge.

There is the config:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
auto br0

iface br0 inet static
    address 10.0.1.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.1.1
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp no
```

VM config:

```
...
    vif = [ 'type=ioemu, bridge=br0' ]
...
```

So, when I launch and configure my VM to 10.0.9.8 - **the network is unreachable from the VM**.

I know that 10.0.9.1 is connected directly via switch with my 10.0.1.5.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

would the following work:

```
ip route add default via 10.0.1.5
```

like was done in: https://github.com/mcclurmc/devstack/blob/xcp-toolstack/tools/xcp-toolstack/build_domU.sh